# How to use TLS Conn.Read to read a large size of data

Tags: go

I'm trying with tls.Conn i.e, conn.Read from golang crypto/tls to read a large size of data. However when all the data is read out, then the program will never stop. Why? My simplified code is as follow:

```
// server 
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

    cer, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.pem", "server.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    config := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cer}}
    ln, err := tls.Listen("tcp", ":2000", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer ln.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()
    buf := make([]byte, 0)
    tmp := make([]byte, 1000)
    totalSize := 0
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(tmp)  //after read all the data, server stucked here
        totalSize += n

        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Printf("prover: conn: read: %s", err)
            }
            break
        }
        buf = append(buf, tmp[:n]...)
    }
    n, err := conn.Write([]byte("finished"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
        return
    }
}
```

The logic of the client:

```
// client
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:2000", conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    writeData := make([]byte, 4096)
    n, err := conn.Write(writeData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("finish writing")
    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    n, err = conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
    }
    fmt.Print("finish reading")
}
```

How can I read a large size of data in the server and after the data is completely read out, then the server will send a response to the client. I tried with net.Conn (TCPConn), this logic works. WHy?

Comment: *" I tried with net.Conn (TCPConn), this logic works. WHy?"* - unlikely. Your server waits for the client to TLS shutdown the connection, or in case of TCP to close the socket. None of this is done by the client, so the server waits and waits. If your TCP code works then the server implements a different logic than the code shown.

Comment: You are right. I did close the socket in TCP. This is the reason. In my situation, how can I determine whether the large size of data is completely read out?

Comment: If you can define "complete" in terms of the data you read then you can stop after reading the complete data. In other words: you need some kind of message encapsulation to define where a message ends. Commonly this is some length prefix or some special character sequence at the end. Also note that `conn.Write` is not guaranteed to write all data. Instead you need to check `n` for how much was actually written.